# Inverse laplace transform of $\frac{1}{(s+a)(s+b)}$

Tags: laplace-transform

Been trying to find the inverse laplace transform of $$\frac{1}{(s+a)(s+b)}$$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Most obvious thing to do is try a partial fraction decomposition, but it just becomes a mess with the constants.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{(s+a)(s+b)}=\frac{1}{b-a}\left(\frac{1}{s+a}-\frac{1}{s+b}\right)$$

Comment: "but it just becomes a mess with the constants." It does not, except if one is exceptionally lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial fraction decomposition isn't so difficult (provided $a\not=b$).  Begin by writing
$$
\frac{1}{(s+a)(s+b)}=\frac{c_1}{s+a}+\frac{c_2}{s+b}.
$$
Then, clear your fractions by multiplying through by $(s+a)(s+b)$ to get
$$
1=c_1(s+b)+c_2(s+a).
$$
Then, you get
$$
1=(c_1+c_2)s+(c_1b+c_2a).
$$
Equating coefficients of $s$, we get that
\begin{align}
c_1+c_2&=0\\
c_1b+c_2a&=1.
\end{align}
The first equation tells you that $c_2=-c_1$, while the second gives us
$$
c_1b-c_1a=1
$$
or that
$$
c_1=\frac{1}{b-a}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{1}{(s+a)(s+b)}=\frac{1}{b-a}\cdot\frac{1}{s+a}-\frac{1}{b-a}\cdot\frac{1}{s+b}.
$$
Remember that when you take the inverse Laplace of these, $\frac{1}{b-a}$ is a constant, so it just factors through.

If $a=b$, then there are direct formulas for the inverse Laplace formula.

Comment: How did you get $c_1 + c_2 = 0$? I see that you got $c_1b + c_2a = 1$ by setting $s = 0$.

Comment: $c_1+c_2$ is the coefficient of $s$, but there's no $s$ term on the left-hand-side, so the coefficient of $s$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a way to make partial fractions quicker,

$$\frac{1}{(s+a)(s+b)}=\frac{c_1}{s+a}+\frac{c_2}{s+b}$$

For $s \neq -a$ and $s \neq -b$.

Multiplying both sides by $s+b$,

$$\frac{1}{(s+a)}=c_1\frac{s+b}{s+a}+c_2$$

Now take the limit as $s \to -b$.

$$\frac{1}{a-b}=c_2$$

---

Try the same thing but this time multiplying by $s+a$.